# Clearing character style overrides when deleting styles in Indesign using Applescript

Tags: applescript, adobe-indesign

I'm converting 400+ documents to a new layout format.

I'm trying to delete a character style and remove the formatting for it. ([AKA, delete a character style with the checkbox checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSJEn.jpg)).

Here's my code:

```
delete character style "Exhibit Number" of character style group "Exhibit Styles" 
replacing with character style "[None]"
```

It works to delete the character style, but it doesn't remove the formatting. Random stabs in the dark, like appending **without formatting**, **without Preserve Formatting**, **without Overrides**, and **with "Preserve Formatting" = false**  triggers an error.

Is there a way of doing this via script? (Can I do **with properties{None}**, by setting a preference to not preserve overrides, or some variation therein?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[None]" is not a character style per say. It's more of a link to style breaker. So any of the overrides are not removed. A solution would be to create a dummy "None" character style based on [None] and then eventually ste to [None] character style.

In JavaScript this would be:

```js
//Removing overrides
text.clearOverrides();
//Setting to dummy None
text.appliedCharacterStyle = app.activeDocument.characterStyles.item("My Dummy Sans");
//Now breaking link to a character style i.e. applying "[None]";
text.appliedCharacterStyle = app.activeDocument.characterStyles[0];
```

Comment: I implemented a version of this using Applescript, and solved the issue. I didn't know [None] didn't behave like normal styles.

Answer (score 1):

As [Loic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1520467/loic) pointed out, the issue stemmed from expecting [None] to behave as a normal style.

The following Applescript fixed the issue:

```
try
    set charstyle to make character style with properties {name:"TempCharStyle"}
    delete character style "Exhibit Number" of character style group "Exhibit Styles" replacing with character style "TempCharStyle"
    delete character style "TempCharStyle"
end try
```